# ansible - if statement and redirect to a file with shell module doesn't work

Tags: bash, ansible

I understand it's best to use ansible modules as much as possible, however for a good reason, I am being forced to use shell module.

I have a **date_list** file with a list of dates:

```
20170811
20170802
20170812
and so on..
```

I need to compare this dates with ansible time with shell module:

```
- name: Read file date and compare with server date and redirect to a file
  shell: |
    if [ {{ item.split('\n')[0] }} -lt ${{ gv_remote_date.stdout }} ]; then 
        echo {{ item.split('\n')[0] }} >> final_output
    fi
   args:
     executable: /bin/bash
   with_lines: "{{ date_list.stdout_lines }}"
```

I get no output at all.
In the debug: I can see it's switching items but I get nothing in the **final_output** file.

Comment: For a start: where are you searching for the file and why don't you use absolute path?

Comment: absolute path is omitted for readability of this post and I get reading from file by "cat date_list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use native `when` statement:

```
- name: Read file date and compare with server date and redirect to a file
  shell: echo {{ item }} >> final_output
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  when: item | int < gv_remote_date.stdout | int
  with_items: "{{ date_list.stdout_lines }}"
```

Or even like this (to make it idempotent):

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: final_output
    line: "{{ item }}"
    state: "{{ (item | int < gv_remote_date.stdout | int) | ternary('present','absent') }}"
  with_items: "{{ date_list.stdout_lines }}"
```

This will make sure line is in the file if it should be and line is absent if condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Ansible's template module to create the shell script in a file. In that way you can inspect the generated shell script and debug it outsite of Ansible.